# Using file path with input in python

Tags: python-2.7, input, path

I try to make some use of `raw_input` and `input` commands in my code:

```
# Input variables
Database = raw_input('Enter a database name: ')
Station = raw_input('Enter a station name: ')
Date = raw_input('Enter date time: ')
Time = raw_input('Enter time: ')

data = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/PycharmProjects/Dane/{0}/{1}/{2}".format(Database, Station, Date), "{3}", conversionError).format(Time)`

    filename = 'C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Dane/20160401/201604010000.dat'
    d = open(filename,'rb')
```

Using that I get an information that:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/Dane/iotest.py", line 17, in
>   
>       data = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/PycharmProjects/Dane/{0}/{1}/{2}".format(Database,
>   Station, Date), "{3}", conversionError).format(Time)   File
>   "C:\Users\PycharmProjects\Dane\iodata.py", line 30, in
>   convert
>       file = d_file.read() UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd_file' referenced before assignment

I was thinking about using `os.path` with `raw_input`. I am not sure what would fix that. My target is to run the code, fill those 4 inputs with concrete names of files in my catalog and run them. Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found an error here.

```
data = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/PycharmProjects/Dane/{0}/{1}/{2}".format(Database, Station, Date), "{3}", conversionError).format(Time)
```

What have to be changed is to make an addition variable, with `input` instead of `raw_input`, because that variable was not a path file, only a name of a file.

```
Time2 = input('Enter time (yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mimi): ')

data = testInstance.convert(r"/Users/PycharmProjects/Dane/{0}/{1}/{2}".format(Database, Station, Date), "{0}".format(Time2),conversionError)
```